# Displaying "Supplementary References" instead of a line as a title of a REVTeX bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, revtex

REVTeX (4 and 4-1) separates the bibliography from the rest of the paper with a horizontal line. I am wondering how I can replace that line with "Supplementary References" in the section heading font/format.  Here my MWE:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,noshowpacs,noshowkeys,pra]{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}

\section{Blah}
Blah blah blah
\section{More blah}
Blah blah blah blah

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{sample1} This is a sample bibitem
\bibitem{sample2} This is another sample bibitem
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

It produces this:
[image]

I want to replace the horizontal line with "SUPPLEMENTARY REFERENCES" (so that it looks like section titles ("I. BLAH" and "II. MORE BLAH").

**UPDATE**

After playing around a bit with this, I found that putting a `\section*` command inside `thebibliography` environment is allowed!  Thus, this code:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,noshowpacs,noshowkeys,pra]{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}

\section{Blah}
Blah blah blah
\section{More blah}
Blah blah blah blah

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\section*{SUPPLEMENTARY REFERENCES}
\bibitem{sample1} This is a sample bibitem
\bibitem{sample2} This is another sample bibitem
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

produces this:

[image]

This sort of works for now.  However, I would really like to be able to remove the line.  Also, it would be nice to (painlessly) automate the process.  I use BibTeX to create the *.bbl file automatically.  While I suppose that I could write code (say, in python) that would run after every time I compile the bibliography with BibTeX and insert the line containing `\section*` command into the .bbl file, there must be a less kludgy way out there...  right?

Comment: The line is just how `revtex` formats the bibliography. They will put it back there.

Answer (score 1):

I did it not in a perfect way, but it will probably work:

```
\def\bibsection{}  
% This will remove the section title, so the line will be removed

\centerline{ \textbf{\large  Supplementary References } }
% Add the reference section title as: Supplementary References
% You can put it in another style you need

\bigbreak
% create some space
```